# Open xml getting images from .pptx file

Tags: c#, openxml

I have a Windows forms app in .Net 4.0. I work in C#.
I want to grab an image from a given slide in a .pptx file.

This code gets every image on the slide:

```
 public static SlidePart GetSlidePart(PresentationDocument presentationDocument, int slideIndex)
    {
        if (presentationDocument == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("presentationDocument", "GetSlidePart Method: parameter presentationDocument is null");
        }

        int slidesCount = CountSlides(presentationDocument);

        if (slideIndex < 0 || slideIndex >= slidesCount)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("slideIndex", "GetSlidePart Method: parameter slideIndex is out of range");
        }

        PresentationPart presentationPart = presentationDocument.PresentationPart;

        if (presentationPart != null && presentationPart.Presentation != null)
        {
            Presentation presentation = presentationPart.Presentation;

            if (presentation.SlideIdList != null)
            {
                var slideIds = presentation.SlideIdList.ChildElements;

                if (slideIndex < slideIds.Count)
                {
                    string slidePartRelationshipId = (slideIds[slideIndex] as SlideId).RelationshipId;

                    SlidePart slidePart = (SlidePart)presentationPart.GetPartById(slidePartRelationshipId);

                    return slidePart;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;// No slide found
    }
```

But, how to convert slidePart to an image which will be shown in my Windows form (in imageList or something similar)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a way:

```
SlidePart slidePart = (SlidePart)presentationPart.GetPartById(slidePartRelationshipId);

                    Slide slide = slidePart.Slide;
                    ImagePart imagePart = (ImagePart)slide.SlidePart.GetPartById("rId3");
                    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imagePart.GetStream());
```

Comment: What is the "rId3" ID?  Is that some constant or something that refers to a specific image?  I am trying to write some code that will automatically pull a thumbnail image from a PPTX file.

Comment: @CoreyBurnett Well I have forgotten the code. But obviuosly it's some id.

Comment: @petko_stankoski what is ID?i have error with rID3 id...in template which part?how can i learn it name in power point ?

Comment: rId is the relationship Id of the slide, or in this case the imagePart. This is never constant, so you need to double check exactly what your "object" id is by examining the xml.