# Extracting image from a slide of a .pptx

Tags: c#, image, interop, extract, slide

any program I can use to extract the images and text from the slides of a .pptx and then put it in a database?

I tried doing it manually by converting the .pptx to a .rar and with some code extract the text from each slide.xml (between the `<a:t></a:t>` tag) and detect if there is an image and if there is get the next one from the ppt\media folder but I don't see what is the tag for a picture.

I also looked at the Interop DDL for C# but I can't find something giving me only the image and text. Only the whole slide like a screenshot.

```
pptPresentation.Slides[1].Export("c:\\temp\\slide.png", "png", 320, 240);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you may try http://www.aspose.com/.net/powerpoint-component.aspx 
or 
2) another 3rd party library
or
3) try parse OpenXML info yourself.

Actually pptx - is the zip-archive with subfolders and files... maybe try [Open xml getting images from .pptx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026705/open-xml-getting-images-from-pptx-file)

Answer (score 0):

Presentation .NET from Independentsoft is also great API for PowerPoint files.